# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 Missing Server Side Dependencies

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, feature

I installed some of infowise templates to our sharepoint server and it installed some features. Now, we try to upgrade 2013 version of sharepoint server. But we take some error about these features. You can find them below, (from sharepoint health analyser)

```
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [eca4173e-82c2-4923-b377-4915a85914b4], Name = [Infowise Smart Action Pro], Description = [Executes custom tasks when saving items and documents], Install Location = [InfowiseSmartActionPro]. The feature with Id eca4173e-82c2-4923-b377-4915a85914b4 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary. 
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [3fe20704-06d7-410e-a7e8-51847bda25d7], Name = [Infowise Smart ID Pro], Description = [Generates customizable item ID's], Install Location = [InfowiseSmartIDPro]. The feature with Id 3fe20704-06d7-410e-a7e8-51847bda25d7 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary. 
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [59286d44-b449-4b4d-8069-71eac251e967], Name = [Infowise Associated Tasks], Description = [Provides capability for adding associated tasks to any item], Install Location = [IWAssociatedField]. The feature with Id 59286d44-b449-4b4d-8069-71eac251e967 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary. 
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [7d35285b-861b-4029-a860-be3f7aa2514b], Name = [Infowise Smart Filter Pro], Description = [Provides advanced filtering capabilities], Install Location = [InfowiseSmartFilterPro]. The feature with Id 7d35285b-861b-4029-a860-be3f7aa2514b is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary. 
[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\InfowiseSmartFilterPro\InfowiseSmartFilterPro.webpart] is referenced [1] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files. 
[MissingAssembly] Assembly [Infowise.SmartActionPro.2010, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23853b1f8d5855a5] is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this assembly. One or more assemblies are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these assemblies.
```

How can we resolve these issues ? We tried somethings from forums but they did not work.

Comment: Have you made sure that the infowise WSP is installed in the upgraded environment?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will not install Infowise solutions to upgrade env. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed missing Infowise features and I remove them from setup file so problem is resolved. You need to remove them from setup file instead of Infowise Dashboard.